# Protecting against Divide by Zero

Tags: c#

I'm running into a problem that I think in my mind should work, but keep returning the same Divide by Zero error.

Here is the code I am using that I think should protect against it:

```
GoalBarValue = Convert.ToInt32(((decimal)CompletedToday / 
((decimal)CompletedYesterday) == 0 ? (decimal?)null : (decimal)CompletedYesterday) 
* 100);  // Divide by zero protection

CompletedToday comes back as 0
CompletedYesterday comes back as 0
```

Which is perfectly fine and as I expect it should.

The specific error that is being returned is `Attempted to divide by zero.`

Is something wrong with the way I am trying to protect against it?

Comment: You're trying to do wayyyy too much in one line.  Break that out and prevent the calculation if the denominator is 0 before you get to the calculation.

Comment: Why don't you `try { ... } catch (DivideByZeroException) { ... }`?

Comment: What are you trying to get as a result on divide by zero? null?

Comment: @Vyrira I could, I just cringed at adding like 6 lines of code for a single divide by zero exception.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I'd prefer it to be a 0.  It's a simple percentage of a goal.  So returning 0 would be acceptable in this instance if both completed today/yesterday return as 0.

Comment: @JamesWilson C# optimizes your code for you, theres no harm in making a "simple" task take more than one line if it explains intent better.

Comment: @Vyrira Probably because [using exceptions for code flow is generally a bad idea](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222/222246)?

Comment: @JamesWilson, an efficient code is not a code done in the least possible lines but something that is easy to read and maintain.

Comment: What iis the DataType of CompletedToday and CompletedYesterday?

Comment: @Vyrira I agree, but, what I wrote above is easy to maintain and understand to me.  those kinds of things are relative.  Adding a try/catch would complicate it in my mine without adding any value to me.  But if the tierary won't work, I'll just wrap it in an if block probably.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I agree, but preventing your application to crash is even better. But you are right, it would be better to do an `if` statement.

Comment: @AmeyKamat Both are currently set to INT but easily changeable.  I switch them to decimal for division and want an int returned for a whole number.

Comment: @JamesWilson The problem is that the code you wrote is apparently **not** easy to understand for you. If it were formatted in a different way, you would immediately see what was causing that code to throw a `DivideByZero` exception.

Comment: I opted to put it inside an if statement. I wouldn't have made the mistake I made had it been in an if statement to begin with. While my mind likes the one liner code better, it made it too easy to make a simple mistake. Lesson learned. @Abion47

Comment: @JamesWilson What should for example today=1 yesterday=0 return then? :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It should return 0.  since they have completed 0% of there dynamic goal for the day.

Comment: @JamesWilson Is it 0 or `null`, then? Because 0 is not the same thing as `null`.

Comment: @Abion47 The old code does a count of all of their completed goals.  If they completed 0 the old code needed to be switched to null since you can't divide by 0.  However with the new code in the if statement i just check if it is 0 then hardset the value to 0 and bypass the calculation entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Is something wrong with the way I am trying to protect against it?"

Yes actually, you are dividing by zero! The only way that 0 can be the outcome of your calculation is when `CompletedToday` is 0. In the other case you divide by 0 and get the nice exception. Why don't you just check whether the divisor is 0 and if not perform the calculation else give it a `null` :

```
GoalBarValue = Convert.ToInt32((decimal)CompletedYesterday) == 0 ?
               (decimal?)null : (decimal)CompletedYesterday * 100;
```

Imagine you would check whether you hit your head against a wall by hitting your head against the wall..... it wouldn't be advisable.

EDIT:

If you want 2 assignments of different variables (as you wrote in your comment) then the [`?` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) is not of much use to you. It allows only 1.

I would suggest to stick to the old fashion way. If you really want the 2 assignments in one line:

```
if((decimal)CompletedYesterday) == 0)
    GoalBarValue = CompletedYesterday = null;
else  GoalBarValue = // what ever you want to calculate...
```

Comment: I guess a better way to word the question is.  Why is the solution I used to turn the `CompletedYesterday` to `null` not working?  The way I wrote it, `CompletedYesterday` should turn into `(decimal?)null` if it is 0.  But I guess it isn't working or I did something wrong.

Comment: with the `?` operator you assign the value to `GoalBarValue`. Did you try to assign 2 values simultaneously?

Comment: @JamesWilson Look at the placement of your parentheses. You are not checking if `CompletedYesterday` is 0. You are checking if `CompletedToday / CompletedYesterday` is 0. If `CompletedToday` is 0, then you will get 0, but if `CompletedYesterday` is 0, you get a DivideByZero exception _because you are dividing by zero_.

Comment: @Abion47 Ahh, that is where my mistake was then.  That fixed it to work the way I expected.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  But since I thought I was doing what you were suggesting it didn't click until it was stated I was a silly for misplacing my parenthesis.

Comment: @JamesWilson You can make 2 assignments in one line if you really want to do it. Check my edit

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
if (Convert.ToDecimal(CompletedYesterday) == 0)
{ 
    goalBarValue = null;
}
else
{
    goalBarValue = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDecimal(CompletedToday)/Convert.ToDecimal(CompletedYesterday)) * 100;
}
```

one line version of above code

```
goalBarValue = Convert.ToDecimal(CompletedYesterday) == 0 ? null : Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDecimal(CompletedToday)/Convert.ToDecimal(CompletedYesterday)) * 100;
```